# python -m not able to find installed module (ipython)

Tags: python, pip

I have some behaviour I do not understand:

`which python` tells me I use `/opt/app-root/bin/python`. 
When I try to call `python -m ipython` the module is not found. When I just run `ipython` it just works. I don´t really understand why this is happening, because since `/opt/app-root/bin/python` is the path `python -m xxx` uses, I would think `ipython` and `python -m ipython` are actually the same commands. Am I wrong here?

```
(app-root) bash-4.4# which python
/opt/app-root/bin/python
(app-root) bash-4.4# python -m ipython
/opt/app-root/bin/python: No module named ipython
(app-root) bash-4.4# ipython
Python 3.9.7 (default, Sep 13 2021, 08:18:39)
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

Comment: Try `python -m IPython`.

Comment: thanks, that works. Nice naming consistency >_<